# no permissions fastboot - fastboot and adb not working

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to unlock my Moto phone using ADB but I when I do a `fastboot devices` I keep getting

```
no permissions   fastboot
```

Even `sudo fastboot` devices is not helping

with sudo I get this `sudo: fastboot: command not found`

HELP!!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try using `sudo $(which fastboot)`

for instance `sudo $(which fastboot) devices`

also `sudo $(which fastboot) oem unlock`

Comment: That worked!! Thankyou Srinivas..

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: There must be a better solution, it's not safe and not good practice to just run everything with root permissions.

Comment: Does **fastboot** require sudo?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, just install `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` to get missing udev rules, defined in `/lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.

Answer (score 39):

Found a better solution over here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127944/1621927

Here is the comment:
 Instead of forcing permissions via `sudo` each time you need to run `fastboot`, you can permanently fix the issue:

1. use `lsusb` to identify your device USB VendorID
2. configure `udev` to set proper permissions when your device is plugged in
3. profit!

As a bonus - it  will be fixed for `adb` too.

For example, in my case (for 'Megafon SP-A20i') :

```
$ fastboot devices
no permissions  fastboot
$ sudo fastboot devices
[sudo] password for kaa: 
MedfieldA9055F28    fastboot
$
```

Let's fix:

First, we need to identify the device:

a) look for usb bus number (hack: I know the device is Intel-based one)

```
$ fastboot -l devices
no permissions         fastboot usb:1-1.2
$ lsusb |grep 001 |grep -i intel
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 8087:09ef Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
$
```

b) look for other Intel devices:

```
$ lsusb |grep 8087
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 8087:09ef Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
$
```

Hubs are not smartphones definetely, so - USB vendorID we need is "8087".

Second, configure `udev` (you must replace "idVendor" value with yours) :

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo '# Megafon SP-A20i' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ATTR{idVendor}==\"8087\", MODE=\"0666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
$ sudo service udev restart
udev stop/waiting
udev  start/running, process 1821
$
```

Third, re-plug your device to allow `udev` to perform it's magic.

Final check:

```
$ fastboot -l devices
MedfieldA9055F28       fastboot usb:1-1.2
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$ fastboot reboot
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.253s
$ sleep 90
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
MedfieldA9055F28    device

$
```

Voila!

Comment: There's a good list of android vendor IDs at https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/UDEV

Comment: There's an official list here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: You'll need `sudo udevadm trigger` as well.

Comment: Consider "0664" mode.

Comment: What does **configure udev** mean?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Actually, this is the only answer. Using `sudo` is not a solution.

Comment: You legend. Spent ages trying to figure out how to reflash my device.

Answer (score 7):

## My Solution

Thanks to elichai2 and this [link and list](https://gist.github.com/jdamcd/6054951) I was able to solve my fastboot permission issue.

I have the Google Nexus 6P so I used the following for my Vendor ID:

> Google - 18d1

### 51-android.rules

If you use the following command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ATTR{idVendor}==\"8087\" ..."
```

copy it exactly. I was already root and tried to copy just the echo portion which gave me undesirable results. Basically it put the \" in the .rules file rather than interpreting the slash as the escape character.

I suggest using the following if you already root creating the .rules file (Use your vendor ID).

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

### Udev Reload and Trigger

I reloaded the udev rules and then issued the trigger command. I also unplugged and plugged the usb for good measure.

```
udevadm control --reload
udevadm trigger
```

### Fastboot

As an unprivileged user I then ran:

```
fastboot devices
```

and it worked as desired. I hope this can be of use or help to anyone that experiences trouble with the permissions issue.

Comment: Nice, I gave the link to the list in reply to my comment.

Comment: **udevadmin: command not found**

Comment: @IgorG. My apologies for such a late reply. I fixed the above typo. It should have been "udevadm".

Answer (score 1):

when i need to send some commands using fastboot ( flashing firmware on htc device for example ) 
i do install fastboot using apt

```
sudo apt install android-tools-fastboot
```

then when i start use it first command is

```
sudo -s
```

then all commands in this terminal will run as root 
sending commands like

```
fastboot devices
fastboot reboot-bootloader 
fastboot oem rebootRUU 
fastboot flash zip xxxx.zip
```

no need for fix or something it's simple one extra command before start it

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/705537/no-permissions-fastboot-fastboot-and-adb-not-working#comment1088961_705541

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add all the udev rules:
Full set of Android USB vendor ID rules for Linux 
https://gist.github.com/jdamcd/6054951#file-51-android-rules

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with missing udev rules, defined in `/lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`. Instead of creating udev rules manually (as Brandon Authier suggests), it's just better to install package `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` [which contains it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/android-sdk-platform-tools-common/filelist).

```
apt install android-sdk-platform-tools-common
```

Answer (score 0):

`**$ fastboot devices**

no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]    fastboot`

`**Solution:
$lsusb**

Bus 003 Device 040: ID 18d1:d00d Google Inc. Android`

sudo sh -c "echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"

sudo service udev restart

**re-plug your device to allow udev to perform it's magic.**

Answer (score -1):

First install fastboot from apt:

```
sudo apt install android-tools-fastboot
```

Next execute fastboot with sudo:

```
sudo fastboot
```

It works for me.

Comment: Fastboot can also be gotten from SDK, and just set an alias path in **.bashrc**