# fastboot not detect my android device - ubuntu

Tags: drivers, android, lenovo, adb

I have Lenovo Yoga Tablet PC 1051L.

I try this :

```
$ lsusb
```

result :

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 17ef:77a5 Lenovo
```

then:

```
$ adb devices
```

result:

```
List of devices attached 
Baytrail678EC0A0    device
```

then I try reboot bootloader:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

my tablet reboot and show DIRIODBOOT screen.
but when I Try fastboot dont found any device :

```
$ fastboot devices
$ sudo  fastboot devices
$ sudo fastboot -i 0x17ef devices
```

or when I try this:

```
$ sudo fastboot -i 0x17ef reboot
```

show me:

```
< waiting for device >
```

My questions:

why fastboot can't detect my device?

How I Can fix this problem

> I have same problem with fastboot in windows 10 but when iRoot
>   installed the `Lenovo driver` fastboot detect device.But I cant find any driver Lenovo driver in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705537/no-permissions-fastboot-fastboot-and-adb-not-working/733299#733299?newreg=e1af5fae3dc74a6ea9e82b29d91e2850) can help you...

> Try using `sudo $(which fastboot)`
>
> for instance `sudo $(which fastboot) devices`

Of course, if it's still actually at the moment...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "if it's still actually at the moment"...

Comment: Worked very nice thnx for advices.

Answer (score 2):

I had two problems that were similar (running Ubuntu 16.04 with platform-tools r31.0.3 installed manually).

First it was with permissions:

Adding udev rules halfway through added confusion for me. Later I found out I never was properly reloading the udev rules. Restarting the udev.service does not work. I had to:
`udevadm control --reload`
then
`udevadm trigger` as found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/820714/867229

And again, if this is done halfway through you also have to: `adb kill-server` before trying `adb devices` again.

The set of udev rules that I copied from a recent .deb package had me covered; however on a side note I found that my device has different vendor ID's when mounted normally versus when it is in fastboot.

Then I could: `adb reboot bootloader` but `fastboot devices` would not return my device and I never resolved that problem (which was the second issue); however this post helped me (actually the original poster has covered this already in their question):

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/81795/357052

I found that fastboot could still communicate to the device and I could issue commands but I would always have to specify the device via the `-i` option. For example: `fastboot -i 0xVENDOR_ID getvar WHATEVER`

No need for `sudo` or `sudo $(which fastboot)` for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's experiencing the same problem, it's possible that you're trying to use `fastboot` with a Samsung phone. After trying everything on Stack Exchange, I learnt that many Samsung phones don't support `fastboot` for flashing firmware, and instead use Samsung's own system called **Odin**.

Sources:

- [How to Fastboot S4 I9500 - XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-question-i9500-how-to-fastboot-s4-i9500.2402631/)
- [Fastboot on Samsung? - XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fastboot-on-samsung.4384381/)

To flash Samsung phones, I'd recommend [Heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall), an open-source tool that implements the Odin protocol.